# Darboux Criterion for integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

My book contains a question-

Using only definition of integral,show that **f(x)=sin(1/x) when x is irrational and f(x)=0 when x is rational** on [0,1] is not Riemann Integrable.

I'm a beginner in Riemann Integration and before I can understand the intuition behind Riemann integration fully, I'm stuck with this problem.
I'm not getting any idea about how to start solving this question.I mean what should be the Partition P on [0,1],how to continue further for evaluation for Upper and Lower Darboux Sum!
I welcome any kind of help for this problem.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Look just before this in the book, see if there is a similar problem already done for you.  Study that proof for help on this new proof.  For example, did they already do the function $f(x) = 1$ when $x$ irrational and $0$ when $x$ rational?

Comment: @GEdgar yes I've already done it.I've also studied the behavior 
of function f(x)= sin(1/x) on ℝ but still I'm not getting the approach for the above question:(